# Centroids in K-Means

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import math, random, os, operator, matplotlib, matplotlib.pyplot

from string import split


def EuDist(vecA, vecB):
    return math.sqrt(sum(map(lambda x: x * x, [i - j for i, j in zip(vecA, vecB)])))

filename = "points.txt"
FILE = open(filename, "w")
for i in range(33):
    line = str(random.uniform(1, 2) + random.uniform(-1, 1)) + "\t" + str(random.uniform(4, 5) + random.uniform(-1, 1)) + "\n"
    FILE.write(line)
for i in range(33):
line = str(random.uniform(4, 6) + random.uniform(-1, 1)) + "\t" + str(random.uniform(4, 6) + random.uniform(-1, 1)) + "\n"
    FILE.write(line)
for i in range(34):
    line = str(random.uniform(2, 3) + random.uniform(-1, 1)) + "\t" + str(random.uniform(2, 3) + random.uniform(-1, 1)) + "\n"
    FILE.write(line)
FILE.close()

dataFile = open("points.txt")
dataset = []
for line in dataFile:
    lineSplit = split(line[: -2], "\t")
    dataset.append([float(value) for value in lineSplit])

maxIters = input("Enter the maximum number of iterations: ")
center = input("Enter a number of clusters: ")

centoids = random.sample(dataset, center)
m = len(dataset)
cluster = [[] for i in range(len(centoids))]
for i in range(maxIters):
    cluster = [[] for v in range(len(centoids))]
    for j in range(m):
    minK = 0
    minDis = 100
    for k in range(len(centoids)):
        if operator.le(EuDist(dataset[j], centoids[k]), minDis):
            minDis = EuDist(dataset[j], centoids[k])
            minK = k
    cluster[minK].append(j)
for t in range(len(centoids)):
    x0 = sum([dataset[x][0] for x in cluster[t]])
    y0 = sum([dataset[x][1] for x in cluster[t]])
    centoids[k] = [x0 / len(cluster[t]), y0 / len(cluster[t])]

matplotlib.pyplot.plot(hold = False)
colorarr=["b", "r", "y", "g", "p"]
for k in range(len(cluster)):
    clusterPoint = [dataset[x] for x in cluster[k]]
    x0 = [x[0] for x in clusterPoint]
    y0 = [x[1] for x in clusterPoint]
    center = [(x0, y0) for x in clusterPoint]
    matplotlib.pyplot.show(centoids)
    matplotlib.pyplot.hold(True)
    matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x0, y0, center, c = colorarr[k])
picname = "picture_number_" + str(i + 1) + ".png"
matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(picname)
```

Code works fine, but I have a problem. I don't know how to display the centroids of clusters on this graph. I know that I need to use a variable **centoids**, but I don't know exactly how. Please give me a hint.

Comment: (hint for a bit less clutter: use `from matplotlib import pyplot` and then later in your code `pyplot.show` (without `matplotlib`); I mention it because that's more commonly done, and the `pyplot` namespace is still clear (and very well known).)

Comment: Why the `hold=False/True` commands? You can probably remove those; ditto for the `show` command (which doesn't take `centoids` as an argument in the first place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, but I'd think you just want to overplot the centroids of your clusters on the combined scatter plots of those clusters, all in one figure (each cluster with its own colour).

Something along these lines can work:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {
    'x': np.random.rand(4, 100),
    'y': np.random.rand(4, 100),
}
centoids = {
    'x': np.random.rand(4),
    'y': np.random.rand(4),
}
colorarr = ["b", "r", "y", "g"]

for i, cluster in enumerate(zip(data['x'], data['y'])):
    plt.scatter(cluster[0], cluster[1], s=50, c=colorarr[i])
plt.grid(True)
plt.scatter(centoids['x'], centoids['y'], marker='+', color=colorarr, s=330)
plt.savefig("random.png")
```

Just use the few `plt.` lines shown here; you don't need more, and certainly not the `hold` variables or `show`. Basically, you're simply overplotting each cluster on top of the previous one, and on top of that, the cluster centroids.

In the last `scatter`, I've supplied the full `colorarr` to the `color` keyword: this way, each centroid gets the corresponding colour of the cluster.

---

In your code, it would look something like this:

```
colorarr=["b", "r", "y", "g", "p"]
for k in range(len(cluster)):
    clusterPoint = [dataset[x] for x in cluster[k]]
    x0 = [x[0] for x in clusterPoint]
    y0 = [x[1] for x in clusterPoint]
    center = [(x0, y0) for x in clusterPoint]
    matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x0, y0, center, c = colorarr[k])
xcentoids, ycentoids = zip(*centoids)
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(xcentoids, ycentoids, marker='+', color=colorarr, s=330)
picname = "picture_number_" + str(i + 1) + ".png"
matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(picname)
```

Comment: Not exactly. 
Using the code that I put in the question, I received something like this: [tinypic.com/r/1zdoo7c/8](http://pl.tinypic.com/r/1zdoo7c/8).
I want only to display the centroids of these clusters on the same graph, nothing else (preferably in different colors).

Comment: The last `plt.plot(...)` line in my sample code does exactly that: it overplots the centroids over the clusters. It doesn't add anything else. You can change the color, symbol and size as you see fit.

Comment: @MarkTrait I've updated my answer: now, you should have the centroids plotted in their respective cluster colour (just keep in mind that it doesn't really show well here, since I'm using random data, and no proper clusters or centroids).

Comment: Your code works great, but I've no idea how to implement it in my script.

Comment: @MarkTrait Ok, I had thought that was the simple part; see the new update.

Comment: I'm sure you're thinking that I'm lazy, but I still learning it. Programming is a very cool for me because I may create something new, but sometimes there are problems that I can't solve alone.